# Close Form of Eigenvalues of a tridiagonal 2-Toeplitz Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, toeplitz-matrices

Thanks to F. Marcellin ([Eigenproblems for tridiagonal 2-Toeplitz matrices and quadratic polynomial mappings](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379597800092)) and  M. J. C. Gover ([The Eigenproblem of a Tridiagonal 2-Toeplitz Matrix](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/271586/1-s2.0-S0024379500X03369/1-s2.0-0024379594904812/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEHQaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIQDvmdP8qTpYrxAKspTZuBEipxVpfz4sZwHDYB3Rqytn0QIgBIu6acGj2fLLaeyP70XW%2Bz1DJ7qyDS%2FrUAt3qQkgTSUquwUIvP%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARAFGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDNgZcSC7tQStRRPwkCqPBXZf4WdpxqxXVaSRZH%2Bz1ZbjbI3ia3Qolp4l9WHt36%2F%2FWP7hCcbUNioJZ3AwNtYAdyEqqCVgPhLCz8iQWTC9ukWAX4%2FtrZgrD1ob7GtUg1GIFlz9tPBwiZcnv2nDxNAWd8QaGBxsvIjceLOzUVkJHpW%2FTFKvVldYaZy%2Fn7dhfja4EIqnfHuUak1wBWyE5m7aTBmlnPaTM%2FkYUrEHLo79qE7fypOaFIoyiKHSswt9sSWHdNcKPI0gsdJCGDqkypIPD4%2FOpBR5%2Ba0MkP8CCJffmUi90%2B7o8k1zlhopD4wGDOPvKfqImjHKLp2BDnJTsXdoqiMKl4XF%2B0ZNqe5zSw3mtsP51mVY6Qy0OF9vtqCHCLcxV%2BZ8V26QXbWcvVPsCI%2FpKJcRC1KW016i%2FkR45pPnaUSPvOl2gbrvOZMnYTQUcyoWzw64kUjQrJxda3BjE7ELFxre8MX9XOiOmrKqBUPnkAXiJC61LGYPP5P61251cbvzIkRQOSjnh1%2BYLOhUB9LRyNrIkyO1Y3EYishVFm%2B2zFwS%2Fr922LlpzpW76fPwNtlcwYmBx0xRBLLX51KFB8FxorUovRY0Kq9eZdhrjs0m73fqglLpdQVuGMs0i8qT9VZpK%2B1Nq8AtkjzXX0sMPU6IH59P1ALrDBNqDg%2FMP3QGCXjA7KLU%2BAKm%2BU1gS0kvHDqMHQ8C1ySui7fE3SMQppJy6eUmqc6%2BT9FblW%2B3KPpqF8f07%2B%2F4JX%2BSqffQY1Pxn39vMijp4cwa9ysUB82qtPXCqmLMFbYdBrOLYC0WiEButOiSHpJBq8PNTNQ0OSEh6VjkwBC8ICRLC9Rp4fyWAVciNub5EtZRAkP63oVkWbISjG6ghqZRM3Vwwe%2FJuWnUyn8wxbniqgY6sQEl4Q1acYe9TUe0gaDf2urVTU%2BRliSDU%2Bj4bTm1RRyAzMEevFBJxeAKkdY6bA0DuvhVBmqak%2Fz143v9ylW%2FuuPxB%2Fh0UPVApTfJMfiDvib1DnuShcc6rOBNmTYEPh2orR82PskVK0XURbzjU4YVUrzd5%2FdkCplP5DBuOw0Jvmd1%2FF3hM44C8F2imXy4wiEMnrrkdeEKJ38Nv%2Fd9MS6QHAbWXxrRCtcVqYuWAy9MS9tdkzY%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20231118T121915Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYV2FKVD53%2F20231118%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=f4358a5fd5695a478f3ef0f1d688f0b96ed8051a649c27cac057cad1cad96d6d&hash=34f0be5091cd1d9c9fa2b58ff57a9548fa23e3292c55520ed7604a8accdd6901&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=0024379594904812&tid=spdf-6e0c5d5e-c18e-4ed5-b695-050325c945f9&sid=509cd81e7b0e8348d63b7448f352122cb9eegxrqa&type=client&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&ua=0f1756535b57515e505b&rr=828029248e685e71&cc=us)) there is a close form for the tridiagonal 2-Toeplitz Matrix with form

$$M=\begin{array}{ccccdcc}
a1&b1&0 &0&0&...&0 \\
b1&a2&b2&0&0&...&0 \\
0&b2&a1&b1&0&...&0\\
0&0&b1&a2&b2&...&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&0&b2&a1&b1\\
0&0&0&0&0&b1&a2
\end{array}$$

My question is: what is a close form of eigenvalues of the following matrix

$$M_1=\begin{array}{ccccdcc}
a1&b1&0 &0&0&...&0 \\
b1&a1&b2&0&0&...&0 \\
0&b2&a2&b1&0&...&0\\
0&0&b1&a2&b2&...&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&0&b2&a2&b1\\
0&0&0&0&0&b1&a2
\end{array}$$

where there is a difference between its diagonal elements with the matrix M

Comment: These matrices should, prior to any other denomination, be called *tridiagonal* matrices.